# Css for Mobile web application in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

This might sound very basic but i have one question because this is going to be my first MVC application and that too for mobile.

- How to design the css for mobiles browsers? Do i need to create separate CSS for different width or there is way to get generic css for different width for mobile pages?

Because targeting different css for different width of mobiles is going to kill me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Media Queries: How to target desktop, tablet and mobile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile)

Comment: Please do a little research about CSS media queries and responsive design—you will find lots of resources that tell you (in length) about how to achieve that with just one CSS file, where you don't have to specifically target every possible device.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take a look into CSS3 Media Queries.

There you have options like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) /* Tablet screen */
```